# Get-AppxPackage of a single user

Tags: powershell, sysprep

Is there a way to get the name of installed packages for a single user to avoid sysprep failures?
Can't find differences in the info provided with "Get-AppxPackage" between one installed for all users and one only for the current.

i've tryied using "Get-AppxPackage", comparing the result with "Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online", with "Get-AppxPackage -allusers", trying to find differences with "IsResourcePackage" "IsBundle" "IsFramework"

Comment: The problem comes when trying to compare the packages of all users with the current one, which are already included in the "all" list.
As an example, if a user has the Facebook app installed, when comparing "Get-AppxPackage" with "Get-AppxPackage -allusers" it will appear in both

Comment: See the $_.packageuserinformation.usersecurityid.username property.

Comment: the "$_.packageuserinformation.usersecurityid.username" property its empty on all

Comment: @GUILLERMODAMIANBORCHICHI, I just realized that there's also a `-User` parameter (to target a different user, you need elevation too).

Comment: packageuserinformation only appears with -allusers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me, with the user sid and the full package name, although packageuserinfomation says "Installed(pending removal)".  Packageuserinfomation (only with -allusers) is actually a combination of other properties that a format file combines into one string.

```
Remove-AppxPackage -user S-1-5-22-3423303272-3025932680-3187700768-374700 `
  Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay_1.21.13002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe


get-appxpackage -AllUsers Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay | 
  select packageuserinformation | fl

PackageUserInformation : 
  S-1-5-22-3423303272-3025932680-3187700768-374700 [DOM\user1]: 
  Installed(pending removal)
```

Comment: the problem is find the full package name that is installed only for that user

Comment: as sugested above, using for example 'get-appxpackage -allusers | where-object {$_.packageuserinformation.usersecurityid.username -eq "USER"} | Select Name' returns packages names that also are installed for allusers, so i need to contrast with something to get maybe the one or two packages that are causing this problem

Comment: You can look in the sysprep error log too for the application name.  Usually the user is the administrator.

Comment: yes, the logs provides the package full name but i want to anticipate.
i think i'm close to get the result by saving allusers packages into a variable, and:
- exclude "$_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityId.Username.count" wich quantity is 1 and username is System's SID
- exclude "$_.PackageUserInformation.UserSecurityId.Username.count" wich quantity is more than 1 and username contains System's SID